# file name in If destination file exists in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: rename, pentaho, move, exists, kettle

Good day,

In Kettle Pentaho, if use `Move files...`, then we can edit the file name in the destination, like specify date time format, so the file like `abc.txt` will become `abc02012015.txt` in the destination.

However, if the destination file exists, we have some alternative way to handle it, which is: [can refer to pentaho website](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Move+files)

```
Do nothing
Overwrite destination file
Create file with unique name
Delete source file
Move source file to folder : use the lower part of the dialog (next option in this grid)
Fail
```

I choose `Create file with unique name` or `Move source file to folder`, but I cant control the file name, it will just append behind the `txt`, for example, if `abc02012015.txt` already exist, then the next file will be `abc02012015.txt20120115_164553` or `abc02012015.txt164553`.

I wish I can control the file name to become `abc02012015_01.txt`, or `abc02012015_02.txt`, something like that.

May I know any way to do this? or this is a limitation of Pentaho Kettle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot specify format with `Move files...`. However it is possible to create a job that does what you want. You will have to do it manually though. Check if the file exists manually with `File Exists` and do a manual rename, or make a `Java`or `JavaScript` step to find the filename you want.